# ggplot2 barplot with total values split into two groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

suppose I have a data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(specie=c('apple','banana','orange'),total=c(1000,500,850),fresh=c(NA,250,700),processed=c(NA,250,150))
```

Note that for Apple, only Total value is available.
I would like to create a bar plot that show both fresh and processed values for each specie, and show only total value for the case of Apple where fresh and processed values are NAs.

I tried with the codes below, but didn't get the plot I want:

```
p<-df %>% ggplot(aes(x=total,y=specie))
p+geom_col()+geom_col(aes(x=fresh,fill="fresh"))+geom_col(aes(x=processed,fill="processed"))
```

Why total area exceeds fresh and processed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rework your data set in a way that your columns name became the modalities of a variable, and all the values are in the same columns.

```
df<-data.frame(specie=c('apple','banana','orange'),unknow=c(1000,NA,NA),fresh=c(NA,250,700),processed=c(NA,250,150))
df <- df %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c("unknow", "fresh", "processed"),names_to = "type")



ggplot2::ggplot() +
  ggplot2::geom_bar(data = df,
                    mapping = ggplot2::aes(x = specie,
                                           y = value,
                                           fill = type),
                    stat = "identity")
```

Comment: nice solution, probably you need to add  coord_flip() at the end

Answer (score 0):

So, you have three categories. These are overlaying the bars one on top of another. So ggplot draws the NA bars, then the fresh on top, then finally the processed ones. I imagine that you want stacked bars, that add up the total numbers. So, instead, you will want a longer dataframe with a column for fruit type and you don't need the totals. The you map fill onto the type as you plot. Like so:

```
df<-data.frame(specie=c('apple','banana','orange', 'banana','orange'),type = c(NA, "fresh", "fresh", "processed","processed"), num=c(1000, 250, 700,250,150))
df %>% ggplot(aes(x=num,y=specie, fill= type))+geom_col(position='stack')
```

[image]